# parse.com cloud code, getting cloud code to see variables

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I have Cloud Code I am having trouble linking together... I have been able to utilize Parse effectively for the iOS side on a separate app. I have basic JS skills, throwing the custom Cloud Code in the mix is mucking things up for me. I have read their documentation, and searched for other examples, it is not clicking.

The first function finds objects that meets certain parameters... Works fine.

```
Parse.Cloud.job("callClient", function(request, response){
    var now = new Date();
    var message = Parse.Object.extend("Message");
    var query = new Parse.Query(message);
    query.greaterThan("alertDate", now);
    query.find({
        success: function(results){
            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++){
                var alertDate = results[i].get("alertDate"); // <- for testing, working
                var toPhone = results[i].get("toPhone");  // <- for testing, working
                console.log("This is inline- Item number: "+ (i+1) + "  Alert date is: " + alertDate + "To Phone: "+ toPhone);      
                var caller = results[i];  
                Parse.Cloud.run("testCall",function(request, response) {  
                }); // <- will fire with with default info
            }
            response.success("function complete");
        }
    })
});
```

The second function is a Twilio feature inside Parse, which also works fine...

```
Parse.Cloud.define("testCall", function(request, response) {
    var client = require('twilio')('Acct SID','Auth Code');
    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
    client.makeCall({
        to:'+17205551212',
        from:'+17205551213',
        url:'http://TWIml-File.xml',
        method:'GET'
    }, function(err, responseData){
        if (err){
            response.error("fail");
        }else{
            response.success("success");
        }
    });
});
```

I realize I cannot pass an object to a cloud code function, nor does a global variable persist. So how do I get the results of "callClient" visible to "testCall"?

Answer (score 0):

According to the Parse staff, it is not possible to maintain a global state across different cloud module sessions.
I run into a similar issue, and I have decided to follow their tip.

[Parse cloud javascript global variable](https://www.parse.com/questions/parse-cloud-javascript-global-variable)

Comment: Albert, I saw that as well. If I understand correctly, I would need to do a query, save objects, and then query those new objects? But if information does not persist or pass, how do I know specifically what the new objects are, and how would I pass info again? It seems to be  a circular issue. Considering all the apps that use this platform, I must be missing something. I just can't put my finger on it.

Comment: I think you should create a class in your Parse project, and store there the information you would need. Or in an existing class (in other words a "table"), retrieve the ParseObject you need, update it and save it. Then, next cloud code session, retrieve the same ParseObject and read the data stored during the last session. Its a bit painful, because we are forced to spend some api requests....

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved...

I was depending too much on the cloud code itself. I thought I needed it for all the functions I was trying to do, based on what I interpreted in the documentation.

I discarded "testCall" as a cloud code function, and made it a regular JS function, and embedded the other stuff inside it and works great.